# Is it safe to cast away template arguments in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm playing around with inheritance of template arguments in C++. I've got a Child class and a Parent class. The Parent class attempts to cast itself as the Child class. Although this does compile and appears to work, I'd like to know if it's safe to do. Here's the code:

```
class Empty { };

template<class T> class Child : public T
{
public:
    void do_something() { /* ... */ }
};

class Parent
{
public:
    void go_crazy()
    {
        Child<Empty> & self_as_child = *((Child<Empty> *)this);
        self_as_child.do_something();
    }
}

void main()
{
    Child<Parent> c;
    c.go_crazy();
}
```

So, is the self-cast unreliable? It appears to work, but maybe that's just because I got lucky with my particular compiler.

Comment: Why do you cast it to `Child<Empty>`?  Presumably you know that it is really a `Child<Parent>`?  (And if not, then no, this is absolutely not safe).  [Nit: the return type of `main` is `int`, not `void`]

Comment: It looks like you just got lucky with this undefined behavior.

Comment: You may want to have a look at a C++ template metaprogramming idiom called [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern), which is meant to address compile-time polymorphism.

Answer (score 4):

No, `Child<Empty>` and `Parent` are unrelated, incompatible types. If it works you did indeed just get lucky.

The good news is that you really don't need to make that cast. There should be quite easy ways to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @StephenGross: I think the `virtual` keyword may go a long ways here.

Comment: While casting to Child<Empty> is not valid, you can use the mix-in idiom to make this approach work:

`template<class T> class Parent;`
`class Child : Parent<Child>`

Then in Parent, you can safely do casts such as `static_cast<T*>(this)`. All of ATL/WTL is based on this approach.